# Associated values from two different file

Tags: c++

I have a vector of vector. I'd like to read its first components and delete it from the vector if it is less than a specific value or if it is bigger than another value. How can I do this?
My code is:

```
int d = sum_et.size();                
vector <float>sum_et                                    
vector <float>sum_ieta_iphi;
vector <vector<float> >v;
sum_et.push_back(energySum);
sum_ieta_iphi[0]=energySum;
sum_ieta_iphi[1]=ieta;
sum_ieta_iphi[2]=iphi;
v.push_back(sum_ieta_iphi);
float max,min;
max=sum_et[(int)(19/20*d)];
min=sum_et[(int)(d/20)];


for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
/* line 312 */  if (v[i[0][0][0]]<min || v[i[0][0][0]]>max){
/* line 313 */      v.erase(v[i]);
  }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
Analysis.cc:312:16: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript   
Analysis.cc:312:37: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
Analysis.cc:313:14: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<float> >::erase(std::vector<float>&)'
```

Comment: Which lines are `312` and `313`?

Comment: the line with if() and v.erase

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're indexing something (the integer variable `i`) that is not a vector.

---

There are also better ways to do this. Remember that C++ has many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library, for example [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) which copies from one collection to another if a predicate is true.

This can be used to copy the vector over itself:

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
             [v, min, max](const vector<float>& value)
             { return v[value[0]] >= min && v[value[0]] <= max; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something strange here:

```
v[i[0][0][0]]
```

In particular `i` is a plain `int`, which gives the error for line 312 of "invalid types for array subscrit".

Beyond that, you have far to many `[0]` for this to work right, I think.

Comment: I know...but i don't know how i can access to the components of a vector of vector...

Comment: `v[x][y]` will give you the `x`th row, `y`th column.

Comment: ok it remove the error in the if condition...
now do you know how i can remove this element to the vector?

Comment: See levans answer. But you can achieve that with `v.erase(v.begin() + i);` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code : `i` is an integer, so `i[0][0][0]` is a nonsense.
Plus, the function `erase` requires an iterator on the vector, not a value. ([cf the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/))

If I'm not mistaking, you want to check the first element of each sub-vector, and if it matches the criteria, delete the sub-vectors.

As alexisdm pointed out in the comments, the for loop I suggested first misses out elements. It should be :

```
// We get an iterator on the first vector
vector<vector<float> >::iterator it = v.begin();
while(it != v.end())
{
    // We check the first element of the subvector pointed by the iterator
    if ( (*it).at(0) < min || (*it).at(0) > max)
    {
        // We erase the subvector of v and erase returns
        // an iterator to the next element
        it = v.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        // We go to next element
        it++;
    }
}
```

The first not working loop was :

```
// We get an iterator on the first vector
for(vector<vector<float> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    // We check the first element of the subvector pointed by the iterator
    if ( (*it).at(0) < min || (*it).at(0) > max)
    {
        // We erase the subvector of v
        it = v.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm I want to check all the value of the first element of my subvectors...what i wrote it's correct?

I add your code in my  for cicle as shown:

for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
      
for (int j=0;j<v.size();j++){

      if (v[i][j]<min || v[i][j]>max){

for(vector<vector<float> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it !=v.end(); ++it){
  
 if ( (*it).at(0) < min || (*it).at(0) > max){

     it = erase(it);

   }
 }
      
      }
      }
    }
but I have this error:
erase' was not declared in this scope

Comment: The loop I suggested was to be in place of your loop, not inside. I'm sorry, it was 'v.erase' not 'erase'. I edited my answer

Comment: When you delete an element with `erase`, you shouldn't increment the iterator or you would skip an element.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed this point. But we should keep the return of erase for iterator consistency, right ? Something like `it = v.erase(it); it--;` ?

Comment: @alexisdm : you're right It can't work either, It should be a `while` loop rather.

Comment: Or a for loop with an empty third statement (with the `++it` done in an else clause).

Comment: ehm...it compile, but when I execute it i have "segmentation violation"

Comment: @Lunatica as you sure it comes from this loop ? I just tested it and it seemed to work fine...